# How to run an application and wait for it to close to run the rest of the code

Tags: windows, vbscript

I was wondering how can I call an exe and wait for it to close and then execute the rest of the code.
This is the code I have:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run("C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\SolitRepoeTEM\SolitRepoeTEM\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApp12.exe")
WshShell.SendKeys "{d}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{o}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{c}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{u}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{m}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{n}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{t}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{o}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{-}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{n}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{t}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{enter}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{r}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{p}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{o}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{t}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{e}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{m}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{enter}
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx).

> ## Run Method (Windows Script Host)
>
> Runs a program in a new process.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> [...]
>
> *bWaitOnReturn*
>   Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to **true**, script execution halts until the program finishes, and `Run` returns any error code returned by the program. If set to **false** (the default), the `Run` method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code).

If that doesn't work because the executable returns immediately try running the application from CMD via the [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc770297%28v%3dws.11%29) command.

```
WshShell.Run "cmd /c start """" /wait /b ""C:\User...App12.exe""", 0, True
```

If that still doesn't work you need to check the process list for your application. Do a WMI query against the [`Win32_Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx) class in a loop until the process doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: this did not work, continued not to wait I close the application.